# upgrade from WP7 app to WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a WP 7.1 app in the marketplace, but some features crash in WP 8.
I don't use VS 2010 anymore and would like to take the opportunity to create a WP8 version of the app.

Imagine that I have a user that runs my 7.1 app on his Windows Phone 8 and that he has already saved data to isolated storage.  Will he see the WP 8 version of my app as an upate?  Will he lose data already stored in Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the user will not lose data in the isolated storage as long as it's an update to the existing app. Make sure you don't replace the old xap, add a new one for WP8 instead.

This is my app that have got both WP7.1 and WP8 xaps. You should see something similar in your dashboard once you uploaded your WP8 version.

[image]